# ASP.NET MVC + WCF + IIS: Windows authentication doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, wcf, impersonation

We have a web site written in ASP.NET MVC that uses Windows Authentication.
We have a WCF service that we use to connect to the database and reference that service from our MVC site. The web.config for both the site and the service have enabled Windows Authentication and disabled Basic and Anonymous authentication.

Now, the issue is this:

If I restart the IIS and then open a browser in the same computer that has the IIS, everything works fine (even from outside that computer).
If I restart the IIS and then open a browser in an external computer, the WCF service is unable to connect to the database (even from the local machine).

So, if we don't open the site from the host computer before attempting to access it externally it won't work.

We are using impersonation to do the calls to the service from the website.

Any ideas on what can be happening?

Answer (score 0):

your WCF service is impersonating the user of an outside user passed to by IIS passed to by the IE user.  You want to hard code your application pool of your IIS we service to use a specific Service Account that has Network Service privileges

its working internally, as its using your identity on the Windows Domain(its in your ie settings in security)  but externally this does not work.

Comment: The thing is, it DOES work externally, as long as the first time you hit the site you hit it internally. After that it will continue working externally.

Comment: It's caching the internal credentials, the answer is correct configure a service account for your app pool with the appropriate permissions

Comment: Ok, but the account I'm using for the AppPool is "Network Service", shouldn't it work like that?

Comment: in your website(not application pool) in basic settings, do you have security set as application pass through? you can try to specify a specific account there as well don't forget